# Failed to build App from eas build --local. i thought it's related with Bundle Hermes

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

I used Expo React Native to build my project, I experienced an issue when building using EAS Build. this happens from "eas build --local" and "eas build". i'm using react-native: installed: 0.72.10

here's my errors

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Some problems were found with the configuration of task ':app:createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets' (type 'BundleHermesCTask').
  - In plugin 'com.facebook.react' type 'com.facebook.react.tasks.BundleHermesCTask' property 'cliFile' file '/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app' is not a file.
    
    Reason: Expected an input to be a file but it was a directory.
    
    Possible solutions:
      1. Use a file as an input.
      2. Declare the input as a directory instead.
    
    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.0.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#unexpected_input_file_type for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: '/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app'.
    
    Reason: Task ':app:createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':app:compileReleaseAidl' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed.
    
    Possible solutions:
      1. Declare task ':app:compileReleaseAidl' as an input of ':app:createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.
      2. Declare an explicit dependency on ':app:compileReleaseAidl' from ':app:createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets' using Task#dependsOn.
      3. Declare an explicit dependency on ':app:compileReleaseAidl' from ':app:createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets' using Task#mustRunAfter.
    
    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.0.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: '/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app'.
    
    Reason: Task ':app:createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':app:compileReleaseRenderscript' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed.
    
    Possible solutions:
      1. Declare task ':app:compileReleaseRenderscript' as an input of ':app:createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.
      2. Declare an explicit dependency on ':app:compileReleaseRenderscript' from ':app:createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets' using Task#dependsOn.
      3. Declare an explicit dependency on ':app:compileReleaseRenderscript' from ':app:createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets' using Task#mustRunAfter.
    
    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.0.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: '/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app'.
    
    Reason: Task ':app:createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':app:generateReleaseBuildConfig' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed.
    
    Possible solutions:
      1. Declare task ':app:generateReleaseBuildConfig' as an input of ':app:createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.
      2. Declare an explicit dependency on ':app:generateReleaseBuildConfig' from ':app:createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets' using Task#dependsOn.
      3. Declare an explicit dependency on ':app:generateReleaseBuildConfig' from ':app:createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets' using Task#mustRunAfter.
    
    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.0.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: '/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app'.
    
    Reason: Task ':app:createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':app:javaPreCompileRelease' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed.
    
    Possible solutions:
      1. Declare task ':app:javaPreCompileRelease' as an input of ':app:createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.
      2. Declare an explicit dependency on ':app:javaPreCompileRelease' from ':app:createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets' using Task#dependsOn.
      3. Declare an explicit dependency on ':app:javaPreCompileRelease' from ':app:createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets' using Task#mustRunAfter.
    
    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.0.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 5m 39s
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.
You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
See https://docs.gradle.org/8.0.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
850 actionable tasks: 850 executed
Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.
```

waiting for help, let me know if you need more information
thank you...

i have tried several ways like deleting "./android" folder and cleaning gradlew "./gradlew clean".